# What is the best way to code a top level exception handler in java

Tags: java, exception

I have a top level exception handler method which has to handle multiple RuntimeExceptions. I need to handle them differently and return different responses for each. Is series of if elses better than try catch ?

```
public void handler(Exception e) {
    if (e instanceOf AException) {

    } else if (e instanceOf BException) {

    } else if (e instanceOf CException) {

    }
    ......
    ......
}
```

OR

```
public void handler(Exception e) {
    try {
        throw e;
    } catch (AException a) {}
    } catch (BException b) {}
    ......
    ......
}
```

Comment: Although I think the second way is really an abuse of the language, it does have the pleasant advantage of checking the order of catches, insofar as if you try to catch `AException` before `SubclassOfAException`, it won't compile, because the `SubclassOfAException` clause would be unreachable; you don't get such checking for the if/else chain.

Comment: That is true. I am looking for the best way to write the top level handler. Isn't instanceOf discouraged in oop languages.

Comment: The "best way" is almost always opinion based, and those questions will get closed on SO.

Comment: The whole notion of a top-level handler doing things based on the exception type just seems wrong. The only thing a top-level handler should really do is to say "meh, something went wrong", and stop the whole world tumbling down. If you want to do specific things, handle them at a more specific place in the code.

Comment: My Java is a bit rusty at this point, but what happens to the stack trace info that was attached to the exception object by the original `throw` when your `handler(e)` function re-throws it?

Comment: @jameslarge Nothing. The stacktrace is created by the `Throwable` constructors, by calling [`fillInStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#fillInStackTrace()), so it is the `new` operator, not the `throw` statement, that creates the stacktrace. If you want the re-throw to shorten the stacktrace, you can call `e.fillInStackTrace();` before re-throwing it.